# Server recommendations for application API

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, configuration, infrastructure

I currently have an application (API) hosted on a small server 1 GB RAM, 1 vCPU (Digital Ocean), the application read/writes to a MYSQL database which is also hosted on the same server.

I expect that the server will receive a huge POST requests soon, nearly 50K request per hour.

So the questions are, What do is your recommendation on upgrading the server?

Should I use a dedicated server for database? Should I use NGINX or Apache?, Is there custom settings needs to be done on the web server?; ex max concurrent connections, connection pool ..etc

Thank you

Comment: Why marked duplicate? I can't see answers to my questions there

Comment: Because that question explains how to approach capacity planning, which you clearly don't understand (or at the very least you didn't provide enough details for anyone to be able to help you).

Comment: Can you please tell me what other details do I need to provide? I'm new here

Comment: That question is  good tutorial on what you should consider when planning capacity.